# How to play Flash games in iPad without internet connection?

Tags: ipad, adobe-flash

I want to play flash games with iPad 2, so someone told me iSwifter can help.

I want to know whether iSwifter can only run with internet connection. If it needs connection, is there any other application the can play flash games without internet?

Comment: Pretty much out-of-luck on this one. iSwifter requires internet access to work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no application that can play flash games without the internet. That is a pretty good idea, though.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, there is no app can play flash games without the internet.

I only found some cool flash player for iPad in aneesoft blog to play flash videos.

Answer (score 0):

No its not possible to play flash games without being connected to the Internet, it's like using a phone without a battery. My suggestion for you is play flash games online directly from your browser.